# Store int in ArrayList and get it back to primitive variable int - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, int

I'm getting an error, and can't find out how to solve it.

I add a int to an ArrayList.

```
int n = 1;
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add( n );
```

Further down, I try to put it back in another int:

```
grid[ y ][ x ] = list.get(0);
```

I also tried this:

```
grid[ y ][ x ] = (int) list.get(0);
```

But it doesn't work, I get this error:

```
found   : java.lang.Object
required: int
grid[ y ][ x ] = (int)list.get(0);
                              ^
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What does the declaration of grid look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a type parameter rather than the raw `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

The error you get is because you cannot cast an `Object` to `int`, autoboxing breaks down there. You could cast it to `Integer` and then have it autounboxed to `int`, but using the type parameter is a much better solution.

Answer (score 8):

Use `ArrayList<Integer>`. When you do `list.get()` you will get an `Integer` which you can call `intValue()` on to get an `int`

Answer (score 4):

`(Integer)list.get(0)` will do the trick. Auto-unboxing will then convert it to an `int` automatically

Answer (score 1):

the main difference between Array-list and Arrays is, Array-list can store only objects into it but not primitive data types(in your case integer). so to solve this we use `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ArrayList like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and then do the same thing, this problem occurs because ArrayList can only store elements in form of Objects because it is a part of the Collections framework in Java and in it everything is stored in form of Objects. So it converts the primtive int to its Wrapper Class Integer which causes the problem.